# any read_stream tutorial javascript sdk tutorial?

Tags: php, javascript, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk

I want to get the Facebook stream of a user using the JavaScript SDK. I can find many tutorials for `publish_stream`. I cannot find any step by step guide on the `read_stream`. I Googled JavaScript SDK, PyFacebook and PHP SDK. No one has written a complete tutorial on that subject. All I can find are some tips here and there about how to ask for extended permissions.

I tried to do it on my own using the PHP SDK. I tried for hours but it didn't work. Does anyone know of a simple example that would export the friends stream of a user and display it on his profile? Do you need anything other than `read_stream` to export the stream of facebook friends on your site? By looking at the Facebook graph explorer I can see `friends_status`, `friends_activities`, `friends_likes` and other stuff that is normally displayed on the user's wall. Is `read_stream` enough to export all of them? (I'm so confused!)

I have no problem using the PHP SDK. I just though that it would be simpler done in javaScript.

Comment: it is strange coz normally you'd vote down this question, u didn't! vote to close it? u didn't, so i think you do not consider this question a silly question otherwise it would be closed by now and i would have received about 10 down votes - so if you don't want to close my question, why don't you answer it? if i have enough reputation i would open a bounty..

Comment: but i'm not able to ask questions from this account anymore because i asked the same question lol - http://bit.ly/rGurlV - now no one is voting down and no one is answering :)

Answer (score 0):

all the information you need is [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/)... the facebook documentation... Scroll down to `api_calls` (after you have read how to implement the SDK)... Its not a silly question, but the official documentation is a great place to start instead of leaping into google searches... good luck

Comment: FB official docs are obtruse and inaccessible for many people.

Comment: How do you mean inaccessible? I agree that sometimes they are hard to understand (especially if English is not your first language).